# HTTP Binding missing in IIS

Tags: http, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

Using IIS 7.5

Under binding type, these are the options that I see... but there's no http option available.
Binding type: - net.tcp - net.pipe - net.msmq - msmq.formatname

How can I get HTTP in there?  I've tried un-installing IIS and reinstalling it, didn't help..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem my final solution was to:

1. Remove WAS (Windows Activation Services)
2. Remove IIS
3. Reboot
4. Install WAS
5. Install IIS
6. Reboot

After that second reboot all of my bindings were back... Yay :)

Answer (score 10):

Go to Control panel --> Programs and Features
1) Turn Windows features on or off
2) Unchecked "Internet Information Services" (IIS) and "Windows Process Activation Service" (WAS)
3) OK .... 
4) You must restart your computer
When the Windows started 
Go to Control panel --> Programs and Features
1) Turn Windows features on or off
2) Checked "Internet Information Services" (IIS) and "Windows Process Activation Service" (WAS) 
3) OK

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 8):

I find that most of the answers below are overkill. What's missing is the definition of http listenerAdapter in C:\WINDOWS\System32\Inetsrv\Config\applicationhost.config

Open the file in an editor (as admin), look for the `<listenerAdapters>` tag. My bet is that it does not list the "http" adaptor.

Add this line: `<add name="http" />` immediately after `<listenerAdapters>`, save and exit.

Issue `iisreset` command as Administrator; restart IIS Manager - the selector is now in place

Comment: this method worked. others suggestions to remove and add IIS doesn't works as uninstalling and installing doesn't regenerate the missing file entries.

Answer (score 7):

Question was asked quite a while ago but I figured I should post my solution since it ate up quite a bit of time and none of the suggested solutions here fixed it for me.

If you navigate to applicationHost.config, mine was under C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config. Open it up and make sure you see http under listenerAdapters. Example shows https but you can do the same for http.

```
<listenerAdapters>
   <add name = "https"/>
</listenerAdapters>
```

Solution was found from https://forums.iis.net/t/1177049.aspx?Problems+creating+a+new+site

Comment: Thanks! This also worked for me. Not sure what caused this. I did remove IIS features and then add them back without rebooting in between. (I meant to remove them from a VM, oops).

Answer (score 0):

I will add this for other dev's who will stumble this issue in the future.
The answers above are correct but there are times that you need also to disable

`Hosted Web Core Applications` IIS feature in order for your findings to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having some similar issues, albeit slightly different setup. Mine was with IIS 10. When attempting to add a new site the binding type field was empty, there was no IP address or Port entry fields. numerous uninstall/re-installs didn't work either. In the end was the solution was to replace the config files located in C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Config. Namely the applicationHost.config, administration.config & redirection.config. I pulled these from a clean install. As always you should take a backup before doing this, also please note that replacing these will cause you to lose any existing sites & setup so tread carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on Windows 10, resolved it with ljsg's suggestion.
In Console with elevated privileges (Run as Admin):

`cd %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\Inetsrv\Config
copy *.clean.install *.
ren *.config *.back
ren *.config.clean *.
@powershell -Command "Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online –All -FeatureName @('IIS-ApplicationDevelopment','IIS-ApplicationInit','IIS-ASP','IIS-ASPNET','IIS-ASPNET45','IIS-BasicAuthentication','IIS-CertProvider','IIS-CGI','IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication','IIS-CommonHttpFeatures','IIS-DefaultDocument','IIS-DigestAuthentication','IIS-DirectoryBrowsing','IIS-FTPServer','IIS-FTPSvc','IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics','IIS-HostableWebCore','IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic','IIS-HttpCompressionStatic','IIS-HttpErrors','IIS-HttpLogging','IIS-HttpRedirect','IIS-HttpTracing','IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility','IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication','IIS-IPSecurity','IIS-ISAPIExtensions','IIS-ISAPIFilter','IIS-LegacyScripts','IIS-LegacySnapIn','IIS-LoggingLibraries','IIS-ManagementConsole','IIS-ManagementScriptingTools','IIS-ManagementService','IIS-Metabase','IIS-NetFxExtensibility','IIS-NetFxExtensibility45','IIS-Performance','IIS-RequestFiltering','IIS-RequestMonitor','IIS-Security','IIS-ServerSideIncludes','IIS-StaticContent','IIS-URLAuthorization','IIS-WebDAV','IIS-WebServer','IIS-WebServerManagementTools','IIS-WebServerRole','IIS-WebSockets','IIS-WindowsAuthentication','IIS-WMICompatibility','WCF-HTTP-Activation','WCF-HTTP-Activation45','WCF-NonHTTP-Activation','WCF-Pipe-Activation45','WCF-Services45','WCF-TCP-Activation45','WCF-TCP-PortSharing45','WAS-ConfigurationAPI','WAS-NetFxEnvironment','WAS-ProcessModel','WAS-WindowsActivationService')"`

Then reboot, and follow  with:

`@powershell -Command "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online –All -FeatureName @('IIS-ApplicationDevelopment','IIS-ApplicationInit','IIS-ASP','IIS-ASPNET','IIS-ASPNET45','IIS-BasicAuthentication','IIS-CertProvider','IIS-CGI','IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication','IIS-CommonHttpFeatures','IIS-DefaultDocument','IIS-DigestAuthentication','IIS-DirectoryBrowsing','IIS-FTPServer','IIS-FTPSvc','IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics','IIS-HostableWebCore','IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic','IIS-HttpCompressionStatic','IIS-HttpErrors','IIS-HttpLogging','IIS-HttpRedirect','IIS-HttpTracing','IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility','IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication','IIS-IPSecurity','IIS-ISAPIExtensions','IIS-ISAPIFilter','IIS-LegacyScripts','IIS-LegacySnapIn','IIS-LoggingLibraries','IIS-ManagementConsole','IIS-ManagementScriptingTools','IIS-ManagementService','IIS-Metabase','IIS-NetFxExtensibility','IIS-NetFxExtensibility45','IIS-Performance','IIS-RequestFiltering','IIS-RequestMonitor','IIS-Security','IIS-ServerSideIncludes','IIS-StaticContent','IIS-URLAuthorization','IIS-WebDAV','IIS-WebServer','IIS-WebServerManagementTools','IIS-WebServerRole','IIS-WebSockets','IIS-WindowsAuthentication','IIS-WMICompatibility','WCF-HTTP-Activation','WCF-HTTP-Activation45','WCF-NonHTTP-Activation','WCF-Pipe-Activation45','WCF-Services45','WCF-TCP-Activation45','WCF-TCP-PortSharing45','WAS-ConfigurationAPI','WAS-NetFxEnvironment','WAS-ProcessModel','WAS-WindowsActivationService')"`

..of course features to install should be adjusted as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the error and solved by working as like above solutions **But work with third one** also.

1. "Internet Information Services" (IIS)
2. "Windows Process Activation Service" (WAS)
3. **"Internet Information Services Hostable WebCore"**

Third Windows feature - that need to uninstall/install:
[image]