# IIS 10 Binding Options

Tags: web-hosting, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I am trying to web hosting on `windows Server 2016 Standard edition` `IIS10`, I installed windows IIS using Windows PowerShell, I successfully configured on previous edition i.e. Windows Server 2012 Standard.
There are `net.tcp` and `net.pipe` selection options instead of `http` and `https`

As per stackoverflow reference: I found following link, but i can't re-install IIS Server. 
[HTTP Binding missing in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773339/http-binding-missing-in-iis)

[image: Actual Image]

[image: Required Image]

Comment: "i can't re-install IIS Server" If you cannot do that to fix the issue, please live with it.

Comment: @LexLi I mean i hosted many application at there, Actually i don't have any idea to revert/re-install IIS with minimum down time.

Comment: Reset IIS Manager, https://serverfault.com/questions/154091/is-there-a-command-line-parameter-for-inetmgr-exe-or-inetmgr6-exe-to-specify-the or directly modify `applicationHost.config` to add new sites.

Comment: @LexLi Getting same scenario after reinstalling IIS by Server Manager>Manage>Remove Roles and Features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question was asked quite a while ago but I figured I should post my solution since it ate up quite a bit of time.

If you navigate to applicationHost.config, mine was under C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config. Open it up and make sure you see http under listenerAdapters.

```
<listenerAdapters>
   <add name = "https"/>
</listenerAdapters>
```

Solution was found from https://forums.iis.net/t/1177049.aspx?Problems+creating+a+new+site