# How to add default website under sites in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

The default website is missing under the IIS manager console.The default website files exist in my inetpub folder but do not show up in the console. I've uninstalled and reinstalled IIS to attempt to correct the problem but this has not been successful. I've surfed many but still not getting the solution. When I try to add new website, I'm unable to find the binding also.[image: look into the images]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Binding missing in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773339/http-binding-missing-in-iis). Also, check your event log for other errors.

Comment: Thank you Jawad, now its working. :)